# jquery не видит динамически созданные элементы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему не видит элементы которые создаются в "on"! Суть такова жму на "span 1", запускается функция в которой создается "span 2, 3" дальше с этими "span 2, 3" нужно продолжить работу но их не видно!

[ПРИМЕР НА JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mhn7eh3z/)

```
<div id='test'>
    <span>1</span>
</div>

$('#test').on('click', 'span', function() {
    $(this).append('<span>2</span>')
    $(this).append('<span>3</span>')
    alert($(this).nextAll('span').length) // результат 0, а нужно 2
})
```

Дубликат не дает ответ на мой вопрос.

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich да у #test нету элементов, но я жму на span! а у span есть  элементы после которые создаются динамически.

Comment: @LbISS и где же дубликат, вообще разные вопросы!

Comment: все потому, что `this` - это элемент по которому кликнул, в данном случае: _span_, а не _div_, ну и _append_ добавляет элемента внутрь контейнера, а не после него. вместо него, в принципе, можно использовать [_after_](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не туда присоединяете `span`-ы. Сейчас они вставляются внутрь первого `span` тега.

Если вы сделаете так:

```
$('#test').on('click', 'span', function() {
    $('#test').append('<span>2</span>')
    $('#test').append('<span>3</span>')
    alert($(this).nextAll('span').length)
})
```

Всё заработает.

Comment: точно ))) спасибо